# Can't import tensorflow in Python 3.6.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, pip

I installed tensorflow with `pip3 install tensorflow` and then I opened the terminal typed `python` and `import tensorflow`.

But when I hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> it gives me an Error:

```
Invalid machine command (memory dump written)
```

I already reinstalled tensorflow multiple times but it won't work. Could someone please help me?

Comment: try starting python with 'python3'

Comment: Which version of tensorflow is getting installed? (should be in the logs of pip3 install). Also consider creating a virtual environment using anaconda. In my experience this way it is much easier to get tensorflow going

Comment: It's tensorflow v.1.11.0

Comment: I tried to install tensorflow in a virtuelenv but there it won't work also

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. install anaconda or miniconda
2. create a virtualenv with `conda create -n tensorflow python=3.6`
   2.5 activate the environement with `source activate tensorflow`
3. in the virtualenv `(tensorflow)name@name$` type `conda install tensorflow`
4. after installation type (always in the virtualenv) `python3` and then `import tensorflow`
5. Always launch tensorflow in the virtualenv. To deactivate the virtualenv type `exit`
   to reactivate it type `source activate tensorflow`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what's causing your problem exactly but if you search for same problem and possible solutions online, you reach here: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/17411.

Basically a solution would be to install an earlier tensorflow version.

Try:

```
pip uninstall tensorflow
pip install tensorflow==1.5
```